Issue with using openURL in iOS Extensions
I would like to implement a feature in the prepareInterfaceForExtensionConfiguration function of the AutoFillCredentialProvider extension that returns to the main app. Since the extension prohibits the use of openURL from sharedApplication, can I use the openURL function of NSExtensionContext through UIResponder? Would this violate Apple’s regulations?
private func openContainerApp() {
    let scheme = "momoshare://"
    let url: URL = URL(string: scheme)!
    let context = NSExtensionContext()
    context.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
    var responder = self as UIResponder?
    let selectorOpenURL = sel_registerName("openURL:")
    while (responder != nil) {
        if responder!.responds(to: selectorOpenURL) {
            responder!.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
            break
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
}


Are you asking about in a code or app-submission context? I assume that you tried a shared application, and it errored.
Have you tried this via UIResponder, as you were describing?
Off the top of my head, there was no limitations to that method in the App Extensions docs (which I've read periodically over the years.)
